# Submit a form with data from other form JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have a form that I want to submit with JSF/Richfaces.

To execute the form action, I need to be sure a data from another form is valid.

So my question is, how can I submit a form with data come from another form ?

My code is like this:

```
<h:form id="form1" >
<h:inputText id="data" validator="#{myBean.validateData}" />
</h:form>
<h:form id="form2" >
<h:inputText id="data2" validator="#{myBean2.validateData2}" />
<a4j:commandLink id="button" 
    action="#{bandeauTarifController.recalculer}" ajaxSingle="true" 
    process="data" >
Test link
</a4j:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

I thought the "process" attribute could do this but not.

Someone have an idea about that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Place a hidden (`style="display:none"`) button inside `<h:form id="form1" >` and click on it with jquery `$('#form1\\:myButtonID').click();` that the only way to execute the form from outside

Comment: Ok it works with that but how to stop the second request (from the button from form2) if the data is invalid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a hidden (`style="display:none"`) button inside `<h:form id="form1" >` and click on it with jquery `$('#form1\\:myButtonID').click();`

in order to stop the second request (from the button from form2) if the data is invalid... You can make a third button and call the first one from form1 , than check the data and in case its valid click on the second button from form2

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm not very fan to use javascript to do that but it's ok for my problem.